# How to programatically access the value of a taxonomy term reference?

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term reference field attached to my user account.

I tried getting the value programatically in the same way as I get the value for text fields, but it doesn't work.

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$account = User::load($account->id());
// Returns the correct value.
$textfield = $account->get('field_textfield')->value;
// Does not return the correct value.
$termreference = $account->get('field_termreference')->value;
```

How am I supposed to get the value (name) of the referenced term programatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the taxonomy term is a reference the value (or label) is not stored in the user entity, just the target_id. So you need to use:

`$termreference = $account->get('field_termreference')->target_id;`

This should be your code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$account = User::load($account->id());
// Returns the correct value.
$textfield = $account->get('field_textfield')->value;
// You need to use the target_id to access to the value.
$termreference = $account->get('field_termreference')->target_id;
```

Now you need to search the label:

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($termreference);
$name = $term->getName();
```

Your taxonomy label (name) will be in `$name`.

Comment: The entity should already be available turning it into a one-liner: `$name = $account->get('field_termreference')->entity->getName();`

Comment: Note that this will only work with a single-value taxonomy term field.

Comment: For a multi-value field: `$terms = $account->get('field_termreference')->referencedEntities();`

Comment: Hai this actually works for me ..  $name gave me the last child of that taxonomy.. how to get parent name of above 3 parents.. like i have a hierarchy in taxonomy.

Comment: @RifasAli this is another question, you need to create a new question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a slightly cleaner way to do this. When calling `->get('field_name')` on a reference field it returns an instance of [`EntityReferenceFieldItemList`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21EntityReferenceFieldItemList.php/class/EntityReferenceFieldItemList/8.2.x). You can use this as an array and access the `target_id` and manually load the `\Drupal::entityTypeManger()` to subload, but that class actually has a method that does this for you:

```
$entity->get('field_tags')->referencedEntities();
```

Answer (score 1):

field_taxonomy->value; not work. Only ->target_id; But if you use the module [Field Token Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_token_value), you could access to the name of field_taxonomy saved as plain text like field_taxonomy_from_token_value->value;