# Get the value of taxonomy custom user field

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms, 9

I am trying to get a taxonomy field in `hook_user_insert()`.

[image: user account]

The logic is that if the taxonomy field is selected as none then print warning message along with a success message.

```php
function drupal_practice_user_insert($account) {
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
  $brand = $user->field_add_brand->value;
  if ($brand == null) {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning(t('My new custom message.'));
  }
}
```

The problem is that the taxonomy field value results `NULL` all the time.
What am I doing wrong? How can I get the taxonomy field value?

Comment: `\Drupal::currentUser()` returns the User entity for the currently logged-in user. It is not necessary to load the User entity that is created, since that is already passed to the hook in `$account`.

Comment: @apaderno , Followed your suggestion and with that i have added getValue() in place of get() and successfully get the field value. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programatically access the value of a taxonomy term reference?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246225/how-to-programatically-access-the-value-of-a-taxonomy-term-reference)

Comment: Hi @cilefen, This solution is not working for me. I am getting an error of undefined method getName().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out! This is the solution:

```
function drupal_practice_user_insert($account) {

    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());
    $brand = $user->get('field_add_brand')->getValue();
    if(empty($brand)){
        \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning(t('My new custom message.'));

    }
 }
```